# How can I make this show only if the percentage changed?

Tags: ruby

I'm stuck here:

```
puts "#{percent_finished.round}% uploading complete" ? if/unless ...
```

Comment: You need to flesh this question out with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `percent_finished` is part of an ActiveRecord model, you can actually just make a call to `percent_finished_changed?`.

**For example:**

```
puts "#{percent_finished.round}% uploading complete" if percent_finished_changed?
```

Here's some documentation:

http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Dirty.html

Comment: You could probably create your own `percent_finished_changed?` method then.  One way might be to put the initial `percent_finished` value into an instance variable on initialize (i.e. `def initialize; @orig_pf = pf; end`) and then check against that value in your new `percent_finished_changed?` method through a straight compare (i.e. `def pf_changed?; @orig_pf != pf; end`)

Comment: So no one line solution?

Comment: Sure there is -- use the `changed?` property. :)  Though, I'm a bit confused -- are you or aren't you using rails?  You tagged the question as such, but you seem to looking for a non-rails solution.  I might be able to give a better answer if you could clear that part up.

Comment: You're probably not going to be able to do it in one line (even Rails isn't *technically* doing it in one line since they've abstracted all of the checking away from you).  I wrote up a quick gist that might help.  Ideally, you could use this to then check `<something> if percent_finished.dirty?`: https://gist.github.com/1005423

Answer (score 1):

Is this a command line tool?

```
last_percent = nil
upload_loop do
    # ...
    percent_rounded = percent_finished.round
    puts "#{percent_rounded}% uploading complete" if percent_rounded != last_percent
    last_percent = percent_rounded
end
```